# Como verificar se uma tag existe em um xml?

Tags: c#, xml

```
// Obtém a tag "tags"
if(xmlDoc.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[1].SelectSingleNode("tags") != null)
{

}
```

Estou percorrendo um Xml e em alguns nós não existe essa tag "tags" e da erro.

Alguém sabe um outro jeito de validar isso ?

Answer (score 3):

```
var node = xmlEnvio.GetElementsByTagName("tag").OfType<XmlNode>();

if (node != null && node.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (XmlNode item in node)
    {
        if (item["tags"] != null)
        {
            //Código
        }
    }
}
```

Eu utilizo essa forma para validar nós.